# MS Access Syntax Error

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I am a beginner in SQL language (neither Oracle or Access) and I am trying to convert this Oracle SQL to MS Access SQL code but it failed with the following error:

```
Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression
```

Any idea?

Oracle SQL

```
SQL> select
  2  o.item,
  3  o.qty ord_qty,
  4  i.loc,
  5  i.purch,
  6  i.qty loc_qty,
  7  sum(i.qty) over (
  8     partition by i.item
  9     order by i.purch, i.loc
 10     rows between unbounded preceding and current row
 11  ) sum_qty
 12  from orderline o
 13  join inventory i
 14     on i.item = o.item
 15  where o.ordno = :pick_order
 16  order by
 17  o.item,
 18  i.purch,
 19  i.loc;
```

MS Access SQL

```
SELECT o.item, o.qty AS ord_qty, i.Loc, i.purch, i.qty AS loc_qty, sum(i.qty) over (partition by i.item rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS sum_qty
FROM orderline AS o INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON o.item = i.item
WHERE (((o.ordno)=1))
ORDER BY o.item, i.purch, i.Loc;
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know, there is no analytic function in access.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Ms Access supported windowing functions.  Your problem is likely in that `SUM() ... OVER ` clause

Comment: My advice:  choose another database.  There are plenty of free databases and free versions of databases to choose from that are more functional than MS Access.

Comment: Access SQL does have a Partition function but the OVER keyword is not recognized. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Partition-Function-1A846A33-60C7-4371-8E77-C94278274DC5.

Comment: Possibly instead of OVER, need to do GROUP BY.

Comment: @June7 - Analytic functions are specifically NOT the same as aggregate functions ("GROUP BY"). And the Microsoft `Partition` function has nothing to do with analytic functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - In particular, Oracle Database itself is freely available, specifically the express edition (XE). Really no reason to "translate" anything from Oracle to MS Access if the only reason is to save money; Oracle 11.2 XE (or perhaps 12.1 XE, not sure if it's available already) runs circles around MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do what you want using a correlated subquery.  My best guess is:

```
SELECT o.item, o.qty AS ord_qty, i.Loc, i.purch, i.qty AS loc_qty, 
       (SELECT SUM(i2.qty)
        FROM orderline o2 INNER JOIN
             inventory as i2
             ON o2.item = i2.item
        WHERE o2.ordno = 0.orderno AND
              i2.item = i.item AND
              (i2.purch < i.purch or
               i2.purch = i.purch and i2.loc = i.loc
              )
       ) as sum_qty
FROM orderline AS o INNER JOIN
     inventory AS i 
     ON o.item = i.item
WHERE o.ordno = 1
ORDER BY o.item, i.purch, i.Loc;
```

Comment: The Oracle code does have ORDER BY in the analytic SUM(). The attempted translation to Access does not; but that is irrelevant, since Access does not support analytic functions regardless of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As a few others have mentioned, MS Access does not support window functions